# PostgreSQL function returning composite type using within sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-function

I have an issue with composite types of postgres within sqlalchemy.
The function my_function() returns a composite type consisting of two float and one text type.
I added the function to sqlalchemy with:

```
class my_function(GenericFunction):  
    pass
```

So now I can use the function with:

```
sqlalchemy.func.my_function()
```

Within a query, however, I can not access the single parts of the composite type:

```
db.select([
    MyTable.a,
    sqlalchemy.func.my_function()
)].select_from(MyTable)
```

This will create following output:

```
--a--|--my_function_1--
'a'  |(1.0, 2.4, 'aText')
```

The return type is defined like this:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (x FLOAT, y FLOAT, z TEXT);
```

Using:

```
sqlalchemy.func.my_function().x
```

Results in an error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'my_function' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'x'
```

Any ideas how to get an output like this:

```
--a--|--x--|--y--|--z--
'a'  |1.0  |2.4  |'aText'
```

I can not use db.literal_column() because I transfer this query into a view I have to access later. If I use literal_column I can not access the view with the name of the label I set.
Anyone have ideas?

Comment: I think SQLAlchemy does not natively support pg's composite types. Try using [sqlalchemy_utils.types.pg_composite](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/pg_composite.html).